# Rank of a matrix over a ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, matrix-rank

In his book *Module Theory* (1977), Blyth defines the column rank of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ over a commutative unitary ring $R$ to be

> the dimension of the subspace of $\mathrm{Mat}_{m\times 1}(R)$ generated by the column...matrices of $A$

and dually for row rank (p. 153). However, he only defines *dimension* for free modules over commutative unitary rings (p. 105), so I don't think this definition will work as stated in general (even after changing "subspace" to "submodule") because a submodule of even a finitely generated free module over a commutative unitary ring need not be free.

I'm trying to determine how to interpret an exercise which asks to show that the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&3&2\end{bmatrix}$$
over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$ has a row rank of 2 and a column rank of 1 (p. 170). Should I just interpret this to be referring to the maximal numbers of linearly independent rows/columns?

Note in the [latest edition](https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10023/12643/ModuleTheory_CCBY.pdf) of his book (2018), it seems he has stated the definitions of rank for matrices over arbitrary unitary rings $R$ (p. 111), and generalized the definition of dimension to include also free modules over division rings (p. 78). The same exercise still appears (p. 121).

Comment: Commutative rings have invariant basis number, meaning that any finitely-generated free module has a well-defined _rank_, being the cardinality of a basis. I assume this is how dimension is defined. And yes, a basis is still a maximal linearly independent generating set. Note that when working over rings that are not fields, being maximal and linearly independent does not necessarily mean that the vectors span, eg $\{2\}$ is not a basis for the free module $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, even though it is a maximal linearly independent set.

Comment: @Joppy Yes, but a submodule of even a finitely generated free module over a commutative unitary ring need not be free, which is why I think his definition of column/row rank is problematic.